# -name: does not work in Sitecore 8.1 Multilist with Search field type query

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Sitecore 8.1 instance Multilist with Search field type the query included with `-_name:__Standard Values` does not work. However, the same query worked well in Sitecore 7.2 instance.

Here is my query:

```
StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}&Filter=_template:67535e3s84a5a71ab2cf8ef732819d4c|-_name:__Standard Values
```

When I remove this part `-_name:__Standard Values`, it is working fine.

Can anyone help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you in your index, using Luke, and make sire _name is an available field?

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 problem as following :

- You need not to have '-' after pipe and before word `_name`

So if you resolve this 2 error, Final string will be as follow:

```
StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}&Filter=_template:67535e3s84a5a71ab2cf8ef732819d4c|_name:__Standard Values
```